# (python) I keep getting an IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the question

Implement the ​mapper​, ​mapFileToCount​, which takes a string (text from a file) and returns the number of capitalized words in that string. A word is defined as a series
of characters separated from other words by either a space or a newline. A word is capitalized if its first letter is capitalized (A vs a).

and my python code currently reads

```
def mapFileToCount(s):
    lines = (str(s)).splitlines()
    words = (str(lines)).split(" ")
    up = 0
    for word in words:
        if word[0].isupper() == True:
            up = up + 1
    return up
```

However I keep getting the error IndexError: string index out of range

please help

Comment: don't do `str(lines)` this is an array, print it and you'll see

Comment: Start your interpreter. Enter `lines = str("hello world").splitlines()` and `words = (str(lines)).split(" ")`, then look at what `lines`, `str(lines)`, and `words` are. (And don't sprinkle `str` over the code.)

Comment: You probably have a word which is an empty string `''` as a result of the split.

Answer (score 0):

For now

- given `Hi huy \n hi you there`
- `lines` will be `['Hi huy ', ' hi you there']`
- `words` will be `["['Hi", 'huy', "',", "'", 'hi', 'you', "there']"]` as you use the `str(lines)` to split on

I'd suggest you split on any whitespace at once with `words = re.split("\s+", s)`.

---

Then the problem of `IndexError` comes in cases like `Hi where are you__` (_ is space), when you split there will be an empty string at the end, and you can't access the first char char of this, so just add a condition in the if

- `if word` because 0-size word are `False`, and other `True`
- `if word[0].isupper()` for you test

```
import re
def mapFileToCount(s):
    words = re.split("\s+", s)
    up = 0
    for word in words:
        if word and word[0].isupper():
            up = up + 1
    return up
```

Answer (score -1):

The string index out of range means that the index you are trying to access does not exist in a string. That means you're trying to get a character from the string at a given point. If that given point does not exist , then you will be trying to get a character that is not inside of the string.

In your code its that `word[0]`.